# Using the repository design pattern with Java Vaadin

Tags: java, repository, vaadin

I'm usually developing webapplication with ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework CodeFirst and the Repository Pattern. For a school project we have to use Java and the Vaadin MVC Framework.

Unfortunately, the official documentation didn't really help me understand how I could do the whole data persistancy in a similar way that I'm used to in the Microsoft world.

It looks like Spring Roo is the way to go if I want to use a repository pattern, right? But as I do not know what Hibernate, EclipseLink etc. can do, I would like to hear some opinions.

Which ORM mapper would you use for a quite small project with maybe 15 domain models, mostly crud like functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In the Java world, [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) is a much used implementation of the Repository Pattern. Vaadin and Spring are [well integrated](https://vaadin.com/spring).